# JQuery Dialog pop not working in script

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

the script for setting attributes for dialog popup does not seem to work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 550,
        position: {
            my: "top",
            at: "top"
        }
    });
    $(".pending").click(function (evt) {
        var data = {};
        data.value = $("#value").val();
        $("#dialog").load("edit.aspx", data, function () {
            $(".ui-film").css('display', 'block');
            $("#overlay").css('display', 'block');
        });
        evt.preventdefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you're either missing a complete reference to jQuery UI or you include a custom build and you're missing the dependencies.

If you open `dialog.js` in the path `jquery-ui/ui/` you'll find

```
// AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
define([
    "jquery",
    "./core",
    "./widget",
    "./button",
    "./draggable",
    "./mouse",
    "./position",
    "./resizable"
], factory );
```

Which means you'll have to include those scripts as well.